# Keep getting : Debug error BC31019 : Unable to write to output file 'path/form.exe System Error &H80070005& VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, compiler-errors, readonly, overwrite

I'm using Visual Studio Professional 2013 and I'm doing some very basic windows forms application.

A month ago, I could do everything I wanted without any problem. But I started some new projects today and for absolutely no reasons, I keep getting this error message when I come to debug or compile:

```
Debug error BC31019 : Unable to write to output file 'path/form.exe System Error &H80070005&
```

It can happen simply by changing the size of a textbox or modifying the text content in a label... It's very random... And I can even do an undo (ctrl+z) and then I can debug again, but if I try again to do the thing I did that brought the error message, the same message pops again as I try to run.

After reading a little about the subject, I realized that it was because the .exe file became in read-only mode and when I try to remove it, windows wont let me.

The only thing I can do if I really want to continue, is to restart my computer every times it happens. Then I can continue just like normal as my .exe file is no longer in read-only...

I tried tor run a sfc/scannow in my command prompt to see if i had any problems with my frameworks but everything was fine.

Since, it is when i restart my pc that the bug disapears, isn't anything i can do or run somewhere to do the same thing. I need to find why the exe file goes to read-only for nothing and how to get it back to normal without having to restart my pc every time...

Please help me!
thank you

Comment: can you manually go to the file path and change from read only there?

Comment: @jbutler483 yes i can get there, but i'll keep getting error message saying that i dont have the right requirements to do so, even as an administrator

Comment: have you taken full ownership of the file? (going through the properties)

Comment: I'm pretty sure it has nothing to do with the file else it would not work at all. Cause everything works fine until i get the error. i can restart the computer and everything is working fine again even if i left the code the same way it was when the bug popped. I'm no good in the requirements things but why would i be able to compile once and not be able to compile once more the almost same code a minute after...

Comment: have you installed any addins? (I recently installed Devetreme and it caused a couple of weird bugs)-my property panel keeps refreshing, as do I sometimes get an 'already compiled' error message

Comment: Nope not at all. You can't even believe how basic is what i am doing. I've downloaded Visual Studio, everything was fine. Made a couple console application like calculators or picture viewer to practice myself. i stopped programming for a while. Yesterday, i created a new project, started to add some buttons, textboxes and everything worked fine, i could compile. Until i decide to change the size of of a textbox (the same way i always did) and coudnt compile anymore. I could Undo and compile again but anything i changed by this point would cause the compile to fail, until i restart my pc...

Comment: i would suggest reinstalling if you haven't already, as it can be quite easy to 'break' a small part of it, and hence break the whole thing

Comment: Since, it is when i restart my pc that the bug disapears, isn't anything i can do or run somewhere to do the same thing. I need to find why the exe file goes to read-only for nothing and how to get it back to normal without having to restart my pc every time...

Comment: try to close Visual Studio, then delete all the output files (all the files resulting from compilation). Then restart VS and try to recompile

Comment: Clearly this is an environmental problem.  Start by making an exclusion for your project directories in your anti-malware product, the usual cause for these kind of problems.

Comment: @Hoki i actually cant as the file stays in read-only mode until i restart my computer

Comment: @HansPassant is an anti-virus the same as an anti-malware? because i have no anti-malware.

Comment: For the purpose of your problem yes. You need to make sure that you do not have another program (antivirus/antimalware) interfering with your development folders. So either create an exclusion for your project folders, or if you cannot, temporarily deactivate your antivirus and try to compile. At least you'll know if the antivirus was responsible for locking your file.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue and it was related to having a command line argument that VS could not find, then when i clicked stop debugging I ended up in this situation as it seemed VS kept a process running.

I could see this process in task manager but could not end it (it started with the same name as my app)
I found closing VS would release this process.

Restarting VS it would then work ok again.

there may be other ways to reproduce the issue but restarting VS seems to release the file and allow you to continue.

Comment: When @charles-desgen asked the question he already pointed out that the only workaround was restarting the computer.

Answer (score 0):

I set the exe properties to Read/write. No effect, but when I set app properties/settings to `"Always on top" = False` the issue went away and is still away.